# Bootstrap styling making icons render too big

Tags: reactjs, electron, bootstrap-5

Im starting to play with Electron and React. Im trying to use Font Awesome Icons in my project but have trouble with that. Im trying to render an icon, but when i combine it with bootstrap 'row' class it ends up being way to big (looks like its trying to get as much space as posible but im not sure tbh). If i remove 'row' class from parent div it renders as a small icon (the way i would like it to be rendered at this stage)

Ideally i would like to be able to use bootstrap grid related classes like row and col to manage layout of the component, but i have no idea how to fix this issue.

```
return (
    <div className="container mt-2">
      <h4>{path}</h4>
      <div className="form-group mt-4 mb-2">
        <input
          value={searchString}
          onChange={event => setSearchString(event.target.value)}
          className="form-control form-control-sm"
          placeholder="File search"
        />
      </div>
      <FilesViewer files={filteredFiles} onBack={onBack} onOpen={onOpen} />

      <hr/>
      In div 
      <div className=''>
        <div className='row'>
        <p>
          Your
          <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
          is ready
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr/>
      In 'p' element
      <p>
        Your
        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        is ready
      </p>
    </div>
  )
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link href="../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
```

[Effect with 'row' class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZvdX.png)
[Effect without 'row' class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2JeM.png)

[Effect after sugested changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxq8v.png)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to import the FontAwesome CSS so you can use icons inline with text and it will inherit the parent's styling properties:

```
<!-- reference your copy Font Awesome here (from our CDN or by hosting yourself) -->
<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

...

<p>
   Your
   <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
   is ready
</p>
```

More information can be found here: [Docs](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use)

Comment: please show the CSS import for FontAwesome for completeness

Comment: @ViaTech if you read the documentation you'd see it's a custom css import

Comment: Yeah I got that 100% it just wouldnt be clear for the majority who don't read links...good update!

Comment: @Nathan i tried to follow your sugestions:
1) i added import in **index.html** file like so: 
`<link href="../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`
2) i changed the way i use icon in **App.js** file:

`<div className='row'>
          Your's 
          <i className="fa fa-coffee"></i>
          is ready
        </div>`

but problem is that now icons are present in html code i see in dev tools but are rendered without height or width so at the end you dont see them on the page

I will update question with changes i have done.

Comment: @simon_aloha is the CSS being imported when you look at dev tools? Seems like the file might not be there and that's why there's nothing being displayed